# RXJS: get the result of an observable before continuing

Tags: typescript, rxjs, nestjs

I have code like this:

```js
const tokenInfo = await this.getTokenInfo(); // Prosmise-based
config.headers.Authorization = tokenInfo.token;

return this.httpService.request(config);
```

This works fine and all, but what if `getTokenInfo()` returns an observable, and I don't want to do `await this.getTokenInfo().toPromise()`?

So far I've done this:

```js
return this.getTokenInfo().pipe(
  map(tokenInfo => tokenInfo.token),
  switchMap(token => {
    config.headers.Authorization = token;
    return this.httpService.request(config)
  })
)
```

This also works, but it made me wonder how to "separate" the code so that it runs more like the promise-based code.

I tried something like this:

```js
const token = this.getTokenInfo()
  .pipe(map(tokenInfo => tokenInfo.token))
  .subscribe();

config.headers.Authorization = token;

return this.httpService.request(config);
```

But it doesn't work. When I logged the `token` object, it's a `Subscriber` object instead of the string that I expected.

Comment: Why does it have to be separated into something more like "promise based code"? I think the best solution is what you have right now in the middle; No unnecessary subscribes and you return the inner observable as you should. Just wrap it all in a function with a proper name that returns an observable? :)

Comment: yeah, that's not how Observables work and really the best way to do this is by using `toPromise()` and then using `await`.